# What happens when a NodeJS version reaches end of life?

Tags: node.js, npm

When a NodeJS version reaches end of life, it is no longer supported and it's better to switch your code to a newer version of NodeJS that is still supported. That makes sense. But I am wondering what happens to the old version?

E.g. I have  a project for which `npm install` no longer works for NodeJS v12 or NodeJS v14. And while I've upgraded to Node v18, I still have older images created using the project code with NodeJS v12 which work just fine. So does this mean that the magic that allows JavaScript to run/support NodeJS code is added at build time? And once a NodeJS version goes out of date, the npm logic is updated such that it might no longer be able to build the code using the out-of-date NodeJS?

Is there a good article or documentation I can read to understand this better?

For reference, the error I saw when I used NodeJS v12 and v14 and tried to run npm install:

```
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/libexpat.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node" "/Users/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/<USERNAME>/git/<PROJECTNAME>/node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/<USERNAME>/.npm/_logs/2023-05-03T19_54_31_960Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What do you mean, "what happens to the old version"? Nothing? Whether or not old NodeJS code works under later NodeJS versions depends on what's in the old code. Whether or not something can be "built" (whatever that can mean) depends on the same thing.

Comment: What was the `npm install` failure you refer to?

Comment: @DaveNewton I know that when you upgrade NodeJS version, you have to test to make sure that the code works with the new NodeJS version and fix any issues. I meant why things stop working for the older version?  I guess my question is too generic. I'm trying to understand how things look under the hood.

Comment: Things can stop working for any number of reasons; there's no generic answer.

Comment: Honestly I found this interesting because just 3 days ago, before Node v14 went out of life, the code worked well with v14. And a few days before that, when NodeJS v12 was also working, the only indication I had that something was wrong was that, the project slowed down a lot for v12. For v14, it didn't slow down... just broke after end of life date. So I wondered if end of life date had a special significance or it was a chance thing that things started breaking so quickly after eol for that specific version. As the older images worked well, so I started wondering about how it's all built.

Comment: But I completely get your point about there being no specific reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to run older versions of nodejs and NPM just fine.  Once they are installed, they don't require any other outside resources in order to run.  They run locally using only local resources.  And, older versions of nodejs or NPM can still be installed somewhere new if desired/required.

An older version of nodejs or NPM will not just stop running because it's no longer supported.  There's no outside dependency that tells it to stop running when it reaches end of life.  If you noticed something like that happening, then it is probably just a coincidence and something else changed in your system or configuration that caused it to stop working properly.

Now, there are plenty of issues with running older versions of nodejs that you have to be aware of.

1. You don't get security updates.
2. You don't get updates to adapt to OS changes.
3. You don't get bug fixes.
4. The current versions of NPM modules you are using may no longer support your specific nodejs version or a more modern OS version.  You can, of course, continue to run older versions of modules too, if desired to maintain compatibility with your older version of nodejs, but those older modules will have the same possible issues mentioned here as an older version of nodejs.

To me, the biggest risk with holding on to an older version of nodejs is that at some point a serious security risk will be found and you will HAVE to do something about it.  With no official support for that security fix in an older version of nodejs, you will have to either manually fix the security vulnerability yourself in your current version of nodejs, change your code in some way to protect against it or upgrade to a newer version of nodejs that contains the desired security fix.  The longer you wait to do this, the more potential issues you may find in bringing your software up-to-date.

**In my book, it's better to continually move your software forward with supported versions of nodejs.**  You don't have to do it frequently and you don't have to run on the latest/greatest version, but there are significant benefits to always running an LTS version.

Comment: That is not true :(

ERR: Your Node.js version is v10.24.1. Node.js 10 reached end-of-life on 2021-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.

Comment: @CésarAraújo - "No longer supported" means you won't get updates, even important security updates.  But, it doesn't mean that it won't run any more.  It will continue to run as it does not depend on anything in the cloud to run.  The OP knows it would be best to switch to a newer version, but was specifically asking what happens to the old version.  Will it continue to run?  That's what I answered here.  So, your comment is not addressing the specific question asked by the OP.